# Define a common pattern for Symfony version tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The PHP framework Symfony is now (as of today 2019-03-12) in its fourth major version. There are plenty of tags for many minor versions of Symfony and they differ so much in their notation. I find it very annoying and confusing. The tags are:

- [symfony1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony1)
- [symfony-1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-1.2)
- [symfony-1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-1.3)
- [symfony-1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-1.4)
- [symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2)
- [symfony-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-2.0)
- [symfony-2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-2.1)
- [symfony-2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-2.2)
- [symfony-2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-2.3)
- [symfony2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2.4)
- [symfony-2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-2.5)
- [symfony-2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-2.6)
- [symfony-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-2.7)
- [symfony-2.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-2.8)
- [symfony3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3)
- [symfony3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3.x)
- [symfony-3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-3.1)
- [symfony-3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-3.2)
- [symfony-3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-3.3)
- [symfony3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3.4)
- [symfony4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony4)
- [symfony4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony4.2)

It looks like there are two common patterns:

- symfonyX where X is the major version
- symfony-X.Y where X is the major version and Y the minor version

However the tags [symfony2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2.4), [symfony3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3.4) and [symfony4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony4.2) stick out of the order. Also what's the point of [symfony3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3.x)? How is it different from [symfony3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3)?

**I'd suggest we synchronize the pattern and keep it consistent for future tags. Consequently the following tags should be renamed:**

- [symfony2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony2.4) to [symfony-2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-2.4)
- [symfony3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3.4) to [symfony-3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-3.4)
- [symfony4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony4.2) to [symfony-4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-4.2)

Other option would be to revert the majority to the format of the above three tags (for example [symfony-3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-3.3) to [symfony3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3.3)).

**Version tag [symfony-4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-4.1) is missing too, although it is referenced in the tag info for [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony). Should we add it?**

**We could also merge [symfony3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3.x) with [symfony3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3).**

Eventually a suffix `lts` could be added to the tags for LTS versions, but that's highly disputable.

The future tags should then follow this pattern(s):

- [symfony5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony5) for the next major version
- [symfony-4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-4.3) for the next minor version

What is your opinion on this topic?

Comment: I know I'm very likely in the minority, but my opinion is that we do not need so many version tags in the first place. Experts may look for questions tagged `[symfony]` or `[symfony4]` to answer. But to watch every single minor verson tag seems like a waste of time, and a poor way to describe the question.

Comment: @yivi Absolutely agree with you. Having tags for the major version would probably be sufficient. However there were some big changes even in the minor versions, like for example with the release of Symfony 2.8. Eventually the LTS versions could also have their tags. Then we'd get rid of all minor version tags except for example symfony-2.8lts, symfony-3.4lts.

Comment: It's interesting to see `Symphony2` and `Symphony-2.0`. I guess it would make sense if you experience a very specific issue/bug in the `.0` release and not in any of the other releases (presumably because it got fixed in `.1` and stayed fixed). The PHP tag is fractured in this same way but I think it's needed since version specific bug do creep up.

Comment: I would tend to agree that major version tags are more important, however like mentioned before the minor versions of Symfony are very important as well. I'm divided on this subject. It would be more clean to just have major versions but the minor ones are important as well.

Comment: You can also see the correlation of major tags to minor. Minor tags are a clutter, breaking changes typically only occur in major tag changes so minor ones shouldn't be tagged like this in my opinion.

Comment: I edited the question with emphasize on the proposed changes. What are we going to do? Are we keeping the tags for the minor versions? If yes, then they deserve some love and attention.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I overlooked your comment, but it is a very good point. The tag [tag:symfony2] is general for all questions regarding the major version 2. But there is a minor version `symfony-2.0` (as well `symfony-3.0` and `symfony-4.0`). If we want to be consequent then they should have their own tags.

Comment: No worries. The biggest "issue" I see is the redundancy of `Symphony3` and `Symphony3.x`. If you're merely upset because of the existence or absense of the hyphen then that's an easy fix with aliasing. As with everytging else jist make the description correct and hopefully people will choose the appropriate tag.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I agree about the biggest "issue". We should fix this. We should also  make aliases for the minor version tags without hyphen and standardize the pattern.

Comment: Any progress in this question? Do we want to fix these issues, and if yes, how do we proceed? I'd have created synonym tags, but don't have sufficient score in these tags.