# Merge [symfony3.x] and [symfony3]

Tags: support, retag-request

Based on the suggestion made in [Define a common pattern for Symfony version tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381169/define-a-common-pattern-for-symfony-version-tags), I'd like to propose to merge [symfony3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3.x) and [symfony3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony3). While that question has [status-completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed), this hasn't been done yet.