# Merge [symfony-components] with [symfony]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

According to its own website, [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony) is

> is a set of reusable PHP components
> ... and a PHP framework for web projects

The Symfony Components are using in many other projects and the Symfony Framework is 'just' a way of glueing them together. This makes the [symfony-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-components) tag redundant.

Instead of using [symfony-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-components) one could use just [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony) instead. Questions can be tagged by specific tags like [symfony-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-forms), [symfony-routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-routing) or many others.

I can't think of a question about the [symfony-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony-components) itself. It's just a list. Questions are about a specific component (`symfony-[component]` should be used) or about glueing them together in a framework (just [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symfony) should be used).

*Side note: I think we should use the components-tags more often. [Discussions about symfony-related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381169/define-a-common-pattern-for-symfony-version-tags) tags focus on versions, but some Symfony 2 questions are still relevant in (the upcoming) Symfony 6 because that component hasn't changed that much. In most cases, a component tag makes much more sense than a version tag. Especially questions about the usage of components in other projects (Api Platform, Drupal, etc.) should be tagged with the specific component.*

Comment: Related (one day earlier): [Merge \[sonata\] and \[symfony-sonata\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410566/merge-sonata-and-symfony-sonata)

Comment: And https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410544/merge-symfony3-x-and-symfony3, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410543/merge-symfony2-easyadmin-with-easyadmin